# EF Entity.Id result in join?

Tags: sql, performance, entity-framework

Given the following 2 tables, where FooTable has about 6 million rows and counting:

`[FooTable] (~6million records)   [BarTable] (~500k records)
+-------+-------+--------+       +-------+----------+
| FooId | Value | Bar_Id |       | BarId | SubValue |
+-------+-------+--------+       +-------+----------+`

**Edit**: Entity Framework v6.2.0

Does a Linq query like the following result in an inner join? Are there potential performance issues with the following?

`foo => foo.Bar.Id >= 0`

If so, how can I ensure a SQL query like:

`SELECT * FROM [FooTable] WHERE [FooTable].[Bar_Id] >= 0;`

Comment: What version of EF?  And in any case this is another reason to have a Foreign Key property on Foo.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft EF version 6.2.0. Are you referring to adding a property to the Foo class like `int Bar_Id {get;set;}`?

Comment: Yes.  Foreign Key properties are useful for this and other scenarios, and in EF 6, are generally a best practice.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind moving forward. I noticed that Db-First generates those properties, but never thought to implement the same in Code-First.